# Use separate fields or single field as CSV in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to save about 500 values in structured database (SQL, postgresql) or whatever. So what is the best way to store data. Is it to take 500 fields or single field as (CSV) comma separated values.

What would be the pros and cons.
What would be easy to maintain.
What would be better to retrieve data.

Comment: It all depends on what you want/need to do with the data?  Are you going to need to run queries to find specific values in the list of fields you have?  Are you going to need to do reporting or something similar?  You need to ask what you are going to do with the data once it is saved?  Also have to think what you may do with it in the future to plan ahead?

Comment: A database is not a dumping ground for data. It needs to be structured properly to be useful. I'd look very closely at your data to see if there's any relational structure you can tease out of it and design a [properly normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) schema to put it in.

Comment: Thank you @Brad and yep have to run queries and do some reports. what about adding data as objects or arrays

Comment: Thank you  @tadman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comma-separated value is just about never the right way to store values.

The traditional SQL method would be a junction or association table, with one row per field and per entity.  This multiplies the number of rows, but that is okay, because databases can handle big tables.  This has several advantages, though:

- Foreign key relationships can be properly defined.
- The correct type can be implemented for the object.
- Check constraints are more naturally written.
- Indexes can be built, incorporating the column and improving performance.
- Queries do not need to depend on string functions (which might be slow).

Postgres also supports two other methods for such data, arrays and JSON-encoding.  Under some circumstances one or the other might be appropriate as well.  A comma-separated string would almost never be the right choice.

Comment: Thank you @gordon. what about adding data as object or an array

Comment: @SantoshReddy . . . They can be appropriate under the right circumstances.